# оператор new возвращает указатель на 0 байт

Tags: c++

Для чего может понадобиться такая конструкция и почему при запросе 0 байт возвращается указатель.

```
char* pC = new char[0];
```

куда указывает указатель в данном примере?

Comment: на англоязычном stackoverflow уже задавали подобный вопрос: [посмотрите тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861776/why-is-zero-length-array-allowed-only-if-its-heap-allocated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представьте себе, что вы пишете собственный класс-контейнер наподобие `vector<T>`. Реальные данные у вас будут храниться в массиве. Для размера данных `N` вам нужно capacity (размер массива) не менее `N`. Если не разрешить массивы нулевого размера, то вам придётся в вашем коде кодировать случай пустого, только сконструированного контейнера отдельно.

Другой пример, пускай в вашем коде нужен массив из `N` пользователей, где `N` приходит от пользователя. Запрещать 0 пользователей, и кодировать этот случай по-другому было бы глупо и чревато ошибками.

Ну или вы разбираете HTML-документ, и возвращаете все найденные ссылки. Если их ноль, какого размера выделять под них массив?

---

Ноль — нормальный частный случай числа. Если бы стандарт сделал массивы длиной в ноль отдельным случаем, то и в нашем коде приходилось бы обрабатывать этот случай отдельно. Зачем? Пользы от этого никакой, а только возможный вред.

(Да, отрицательные числа — не нормальный случай. У нас может быть ноль пользователей, но не может быть −1 пользователь.)

---

Ваш код возвращает какой-то ненулевой указатель. Сколько именно байт реально аллоцируется — подробности имплементации стандартной библиотеки вашего компилятора. В любом случае вы не имеете права *разыменовывать* полученный указатель.

Comment: Это все невалидные примеры. Для контейнера наподобие вектор как раз стоит кодировать случай пустого, только сконструированного контейнера отдельно, так как тогда конструктор по-умолчанию будет легковесной `noexcept` функцией. Во втором и третьем случае, если пользователей или элементов 0, то и массив можно вообще не выделять.

Comment: @VTT: Ага, и иметь в коде всегда проверку. Очень хороший дизайн.

Comment: Да, проверять крайние случаи - это хороший дизайн.

Comment: @VTT: И смысл добавлять медленную проверку, если её можно легко обойти? Усложнять себе жизнь?

Comment: Что значит "медленную"? Такого рода проверки обычно ускоряют код, тем больше, чем чаще встречается ситуация "пустого" задания и чем тяжелее обработка "непустого" задания. Если обработка подразумевает создание некоторых промежуточных объектов, то такая проверка вообще *обязательна*. Первый же ваш пример с вектором демонстрирует что такого рода проверка предпочтительна в плане производительности, никому в голуву даже не придет выделять массив нулевой длины в конструкторе по-умолчанию.

Comment: @VTT: Лишняя проверка — это ускорение? Я надеюсь, вы можете подкрепить ваши слова бенчмарком?

Comment: [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MfgGYFlmeyW0kZ8k). Вы сами-то предже чем писать про "медленную" проверку что-нибудь меряли? А если для обработки массива надо будет допустим выделить временный файл на пару Гб?

Comment: @VTT: И что с чем сравнивает ваш пример, простите? А что с чем нужно?

Comment: Обработку массивов варьирующейся длины без проверки ситуации, когда длина равно 0 и с проверкой такой ситуации. Как видно, даже в таком простом случае дополнительная проверка не только не замедляет, но наоборот, ускоряет выполнение программы.

Comment: @VTT: Не-не-не, вы сравниваете не то, о чём говорю я. Сравнивайте реализацию вектора с проверкой на `null` при каждой операции, и без неё. Ваш код имеет к теме нашего обсуждения весьма далёкое отношение.

Comment: @VTT: Ну и ваш тест сравнивает время создания — единственное, на чём проверка длины помогает. Но всем известно, что вектор создают редко, а намного чаще читают, пишут, добавляют и убирают элементы. Делайте более реальный бенчмарк.

Comment: _"возвращает какой-то ненулевой указатель ... вы не имеете права разыменовывать полученный указатель"_ - а почему ненулевой?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Потому что `new`. `malloc` вот в некоторых реализациях возвращает `nullptr` в таких условиях.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вот тут ссылка на стандарт: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861807/276994: «C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer.»

Comment: Ага, уже увидел, когда тот ответ читал. Хотя не понимаю, какая разница, если разыменовывать его нельзя...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, разница в проверках. Если бы указатель был нулевым, надо было бы писать `if (data == nullptr && size != 0) data = new T[size];`. А с текущим положением вещей — просто `if (data == nullptr) data = new T[size];`.

Comment: Я имею в виду, зачем надо, чтобы `new T[0]` вернул не 0 - какая практическая польза? А с проверками создания ясно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну вот с таким кодом можно делать ленивое создание как у меня без лишней проверки, это раз. Во-вторых, без этого `nullptr` везде означал бы «данные не выделены ИЛИ в запросе был указана длина 0». Это достаточно неизящная семантика. Чтобы выяснить, какой из этих двух случаев имел место, пришлось бы делать дополнительную проверку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70342/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).